# tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2020)

Tags: texlive

I understand this question has been asked several times before in different forms, however none of the answers fully resolve it for me.

Simply:

```
$ user: sudo tlmgr install chemmacros
```

returns:

```
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2020)
```

However I have done a fresh install of texlive:

```
$ user: tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020)
```

and:

```
$ user: tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 57119 (2020-12-13 00:40:00 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2020
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2020
```

From what I have read there seems to be an issue with how debian/Ubuntu treats the default tex installation in some way. As a last resort I will downgrade the repository, but I'd like to be able to update a package whenever necessary. For ref. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1

Is there a possible way for this to work via tlmgr?

Comment: You probably have two latex installations and your sudo version hits the wrong one. What exactly did you install? A full installation already include chemmacros

Comment: You are 100% correct, `$ sudo tlmgr --version` returns the 2017 version, and chemmacros was installed with my texlive installation (from tug.org). Indeed I knew I had two installations (ubuntu comes with a default tex I believe), I thought the reinstallation would change the binaries (which it did, but not for root). So I can invoke tlmgr from the installation, but it won't allow me to change the files in the installation. This then leaves me unable to update my installation as it requires root access, but `$ sudo tlmgr` uses the 2017 one.

Comment: Use sudo with the full path to the proper tlmgr. Note that Ubuntu does not install texlive by default, it probably came via a recommends for an editor

Comment: Yeah this an okay solution, is there anyway to make it more permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/my_os/tlmgr install <package>`

Works as a solution, with thanks to @daleif. I was not aware that installing a new texlive installation does not remove the tex 2017 root binaries, even though it changes the user binaries.

Comment: It does change the binaries, but the Ubuntu binaries (2017) that you have installed is listed first in the path (or even your manual addition of the 2020 version does not even apply to sudo)

Comment: Of course, my mistake.